# How to select text between html <label> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given following html:

```
<label for="xxxx" id="Password_label">
   <div class="xxxx">Password 555</div>
   555
   <div class="xxx"></div>
</label>
```

I need to replace the text "555" written inside the label element below the first div. I am trying to get the text but not able to do so far.

I tried:

```
$("#Password_label").text()
```

But it is returning empty string.

Comment: where/how did you run that `.text()` call?

Comment: It's logging allright to me: "Password 555, 555"

Comment: `div`/`label` - no difference. See duplicate.

Comment: @MarcB from the browser console

Comment: @Jamiec I had to modify already existing web application's html by injecting JavaScript. So was not able to modify the html structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text node with help of **[`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents)** and **[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)** then replace the text using **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith)**.

```js
$('#Password_label')
  .contents() // get all nodes including text node
  .eq(2) // get the text node 
  .replaceWith('newText') // replace with new content
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="xxxx" id="Password_label">
  <div class="xxxx">Password 555</div>
  555
  <div class="xxx"></div>
</label>
```

---

With pure JavaScript use **[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)** to get all child nodes and update text content using **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property of node.

```js
document.getElementById('Password_label') // get element by id
  .childNodes[2] // get all childnodes and get text node need to update
  .textContent = 'newText'; // update text content of that node
```

```html
<label for="xxxx" id="Password_label">
  <div class="xxxx">Password 555</div>
  555
  <div class="xxx"></div>
</label>
```

---

**UPDATE :** In this certain case you can avoid the problem of empty text node by **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)** method

```js
$('#Password_label')
  .contents() // get all nodes including text node
  .filter(function() { // filterout non-empty text nodes
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.textContent).length;
  })
  .replaceWith('newText') // replace with new content
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="xxxx" id="Password_label">
  <div class="xxxx">Password 555</div>
  555
  <div class="xxx"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Correct. But for me it worked with $('#Password_label').contents().eq(1).replaceWith('newText'). I needed to replace the text between the two divs i.e. "555"

Comment: @KhadimAli in the above fiddle there is whitespace before the div , it will act as textnode